# Handle the Sliders Control with Edit Box in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, slider, controls, editbox

I have a problem with appropriate using Slider Control and good understanding of mechanism of UpdatingData of values.
This is a very simple program which should help me get understood of problem.

Take a look on my code:

```
// TestDialog.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ControlsandVariables.h"
#include "TestDialog.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// TestDialog dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(TestDialog, CDialog)

TestDialog::TestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(TestDialog::IDD, pParent)
    , editbox_value(0)
    , slider_value(0)
{

}

TestDialog::~TestDialog()
{
}

void TestDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SLIDER1, slider_ctrl);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, editbox_value);
    DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, editbox_value, 0, 99);
    DDX_Slider(pDX, IDC_SLIDER1, slider_value);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(TestDialog, CDialog)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, IDC_SLIDER1, &TestDialog::OnNMCustomdrawSlider1)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &TestDialog::OnEnChangeEdit1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// TestDialog message handlers


void TestDialog::OnNMCustomdrawSlider1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    
    int value = slider_ctrl.GetPos();
    editbox_value = value;
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    
    //editbox_value = slider_value;
    //UpdateData(TRUE);
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

I have a problem with change the value on slider and edit box simultanously.
If I use `UpadateData(TRUE)` the value of slider is changing but edit box remains unchanged.
On the other hand, if I set `UpdateData (FALSE)` the slider remains unchanged but editbox value is changing and after iteration comeback to 0.
How to achieve the state where both slider and editbox change their values ​​depending on each other.
I would like to mention that this is a WindowsEmbedded 2013 version of the MFC library, not for local Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create two control type variables for `CEdit` and `CSliderCtrl`. example:

- `m_cedit`
- `m_slider`

[image]

[image]

Remarques :

- `CSliderCtrl` send a `WM_HSCROLL` message
- Assure that `CEdit` **Number** property is set to **True**

Add the following functions to the Dlg header class:

```
afx_msg void OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
afx_msg void OnEnChangeEdit();
```

And in CPP:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCSpinerDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_HSCROLL() // Called when Slider is scrolled
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, OnEnChangeEdit) // Called when CEdit change value
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CMFCSpinerDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    CSliderCtrl* pSlider = reinterpret_cast<CSliderCtrl*>(pScrollBar);

    // You can have multiple sliders: Check which one sent the notification  
    if (pSlider == &m_slider)
    {
        CString strSliderValue;
        int iValue = m_slider.GetPos(); // Get Slider value
        strSliderValue.Format("%d", iValue); 

        m_cedit.SetWindowText(strSliderValue); // Change CEdit Value
    }
}

void CMFCSpinerDlg::OnEnChangeEdit()
{
    CString strEditValue;
    m_cedit.GetWindowText(strEditValue);
    int iCeditValue = atoi(strEditValue);
    
    // do other check on value ...
    m_slider.SetPos(iCeditValue); // set Slider value
}
```

By doing this :

- If you change `CSliderCtrl` Value -> `CEdit` change
- If you change `CEdit` Value  -> `CSliderCtrl` change